# "great indemnities" as a metaphor

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors

In *Diana of the Crossways*, Lady Dunstane does not like her new house: she thinks it is too ugly. Her friend Diana, however, says that many people would be happy to have a house like that. My question is: what is meant here by *indemnities*?

> Her cat's love of the familiar inside corners was never able to embrace the outer walls. Her sensitiveness, too, was racked by the presentation of so pitiably ugly a figure to the landscape. She likened it to a coarse-featured country wench, whose cleaning and decorating of her countenance makes complexion grin and ruggedness yawn. Dirty, dilapidated, hung with weeds and parasites, it would have been more tolerable. She tried the effect of various creepers, and they were as a staring paint. What it was like then, she had no heart
>   to say.
>
> One may, however, fall on a pleasureable resignation in **accepting great indemnities,** as Diana bade her believe, when the first disgust began to ebb. "A good hundred over there would think it a Paradise for an asylum: she signified London."

I undestand the literal meaning of *indemnities*, but do not understand what does it signify here: an *indemnity* is a compensation, but who pays it in this context? Or maybe she refers to the landscape of the estate which, unlike the house, both of them find beautiful?

Comment: Good question... Could be sloppiness or poor choice of words on the author's part...

Comment: Or does Diana simply mean that theoretically Lady Dunstane can give the house up, the house itself being a compensation? (As later on they talk about politics)

Comment: I think the likely interpretation is that Lady Dunstane is resigning herself to live in the house. Her disgust for it is fading and she is resignedly accepting the cost (indemnities) of living there. The metaphorical cost is putting up with the things she doesn't like.

Comment: @Silenus An accepted indemnity is not a cost, but a benefit. It can mean compensation, but it can also mean a surety against loss or an exemption from legal responsibility. Neither sense helps me understand the sentence given the limited context that I read.

Comment: I was using it as a cost in this sense "a sum of money paid as compensation, especially a sum exacted by a victor in war as one condition of peace" (Oxford). Lady Dunstane might be "accepting", that is, willing, to pay the indemnities. But I don't know. It's a tough (or poorly worded) cookie.

Comment: As per deadrat, indemnities generally guarantee against things undesirable.

Diana of the Crossways was written by George Meredith (1828-1909) and published in 1885. All other things being equal it should be more easily understandable than, say, Dickens or Rider Haggard but just you try reading it. I foresee such  difficulty following more than a few words, few modern readers will handle a paragraph.

There seems little evidence of any metaphor but “accepting great indemnities” might cover her taking a house as one-off payment to let an aunt or uncle out of a duty to support her.

Comment: Pretty sure the 'indemnities' referred to here are metaphorical rather than literal. It isn't about paying of accepting monies or liabilities. Rather the knowledge that others would envy her possession of the property *A good hundred over there would think it a Paradise* is the compensation which allows her to resign herself with some pleasure to the outward look of the place.

Comment: There's a vague possibility that it's a misspelling of "indignities".

Answer (score 1):

The key quote might be annotated as:

> One (a person such as the Lady Dunstane) may, however, fall on a pleasureable resignation (enjoy the feeling of giving in and accepting)   great indemnities (the way one is paid back or recompensed for accepting the thing they rejected), as Diana bade her believe....

To perhaps over-unpack, Diana is understood to have told Lady Dunstane something like this:

> "Just give in and accept this place that you dislike. It is the envy of many. Once you have resigned yourself to accept it, your resignation will be pleasureable if you can accept enjoyment of the good parts of your estate as payment for tolerating the bad parts."